Facing issue while connecting with MySQL database in SpringBoot project
Below is my application.properties file.In code i have used annotayion of "@Table(name="Emp1")"
In the mentioned database in application.properties, it is not creating the table automatically in database.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

server.port=4040
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update





The connection to the dbms is established w/o errors and the database itself exists?

Do you want the table to persist or create every time on each application startup?

Did you set the DB password to 'root?' Often it is null by default, you may be confusing it

So just another question where the questioner never comes back to help to further investigate his own problem. This is just a shame. Besides the usual closing of such questions, maybe these kind of users who are just stealing valuable time from other users should get some kind of a strike and eventually be banned.

I am sorry for inconvenience my phone was dead. Above you mentioned that my code runs without an error but facing problem to connect with DB. That is true, my DB itself exist. But i was not able to create table in my DB automatically can you tell me what should I do?
